# Rails application access is very slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, latency

We are trying to access a Rails application running on a Ubuntu machine from a Windows machine and the time it takes to load the application is extremely slow. The ping operation from the Windows machine to the Ubuntu machine comes back in < 1ms. How do I debug this issue?

Comment: Try  connecting Rails from some one else machine is it slow on that regard too then perhaps make sure your not running on `webrick` if that too is not then perhaps you need to look at the application log to figure out where it taking that much time `newrelic` in development could be a best bet to figure that out also which rails version

Comment: This slowness happens only when we access from a certain Windows machine, access from other machines seems to load the app quickly. We are using Rails 3.2.8 and we are starting the app using the rails s command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running your rails applications with command 'rails server' which by default a webrick, it will take time for other machines to load, try installing the application in apache server within your ubuntu machine and access it with your system ip and the symlink.(http://0.0.0.0/symlink) For the first time when you restart your apache server, it will take time and then it should load in shorter time than in webrick.